How do i implement provisioned concurrency for aws lambda using serverless that will activitate only in peak hour?
I want to implement provisioned concurrency feature in aws lambda but that will be activated only in peek hours.
I don't want to run my instance 24x7, so i can cut conner my bills
I've configured my serverless to provide 150 provisioned concurrency but they will run all time.
serverless.yml
functions:
  api:
    handler: index.handler
    provisionedConcurrency: 150


You can use serverless-provisioned-concurrency-autoscaling plugin to schedule the aws lambda provisioned concurrency
Basically this plugin will create two scheduled actions to start and stop the execution environment with the help of application autoscaling

open terminal and run the below command to install plugin
npm i serverless-provisioned-concurrency-autoscaling


Then configure the plugin in serverless.yml
plugins:
  - serverless-provisioned-concurrency-autoscaling


This is final important step, configuring the start and end time of lambda execution environment under the function level
functions:
api:
    handler: index.handler
    provisionedConcurrency: 150
    memorySize: 512

    #For auto scaling in peek hours
    concurrencyAutoscaling:
    enabled: true
    alias: provisioned
    maximum: 150
    minimum: 0
    usage: 0.75
    scaleInCooldown: 0
    scaleOutCooldown: 0
    customMetric:
        statistic: maximum
    scheduledActions:
        - name: PeekHourStarts
        timezone: "Your Timezone" #default to UTC
        schedule: "cron(00 9 * * ? *)"
        action:
            minimum: 150
        - name: PeekHourEnds
        timezone: "Your Timezone" #default to UTC
        schedule: "cron(00 12 * * ? *)"
        action:
            maximum: 0
            minimum: 0



Bonus

Plugin Doc
AWS supported timezones
AWS cron expressions reference

